# not redirected to any where after ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I used the jQuery fileupload plugin to upload multiple pictures. I set up the plugin as:

```
$(function(){
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
      url: "/polls",
      dataType: "html"
    });
  })
```

The PollsController(in short):

```
def new
    authenticate
    @poll = Poll.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

def create
    @poll.nil? ? @poll = Poll.create(params[:poll]) : @poll.update_attributes(params[:poll])
    if @poll.errors.full_messages.empty?
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html{ redirect_to @poll }
      end   
    else
      flash[:"alert-error"] = @poll.errors.full_messages
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html{ redirect_to '/polls/new' }
      end  
    end
end
```

I was testing the validation, so I got after submit the form:

```
 ...
    (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/polls/new
Completed 302 Found in 644ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)


Started GET "/polls/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-20 16:27:31 -0800
Processing by PollsController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 18 LIMIT 1
  Rendered polls/_template.haml (0.1ms)
  Rendered polls/_jQuery_fileupload_plugin.haml (5.9ms)
  Rendered polls/new.haml within layouts/application (14.3ms)
  Rendered sessions/_signin.haml (3.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.haml (5.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.haml (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 42ms (Views: 38.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

But the page was not actually reloaded.Why did it happen?

Thanks

Comment: responding with redirects to ajax doesn't redirect the browser, but that ajax request

Comment: @Esailija so how can I do that? Could you give me any suggestions in more details? Thanks

Comment: Attach a callback function to fileupload and set `location.href = "xxx";` in javascript